# Resetting command buffer

Tags: vulkan

Does resetting command buffer require the number of call to `vkCmd*` in the command buffer to remain constant? Because I segfault as soon as I add one extra draw call to command buffer after resetting and resubmitting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does resetting command buffer require the number of call to vkCmd* in the command buffer to remain constant?

No. If you're getting a crash, then either the implementation is buggy or something else is buggy in your code.

Answer (score 4):

If you're resetting a command buffer, make sure that it is no longer in use by waiting on it's submission fence before resetting it. Other than that there should be no limitations in any of the calls put into a CB after it has been reset.